# Sitecore 9.0.1 Geo-location service login

Tags: geo-location

While I am trying to access the services of `geolocation` in Sitecore first we have to log in.

Whereas when I am typing my credentials It shows Invalid credentials and when I am trying to do it by clicking on `new user` or `forget password` it throws an error like--

`The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.`

Please help me

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you haven't done it already, you have to go through your account manager to get special permissions to login through the app center.  I had to do this for SC9 as well.  I had to fill out [this form](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/54424858e4b06e8b47dc7c92/t/5d25230ad68d350001143973/1562714890605/Request+for+App+Center+Access.pdf) & have app center access permissions associated with my Sitecore Portal login.

Comment: Thankyou for the help.